# How do I flush DNS entries in my VPC in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I recently added VPC Endpoints to my CloudFormation stack. I then deleted my stack and tried to recreate it.

When I tried to recreate it, I got the following error:

```
private-dns-enabled cannot be set because there is already a conflicting DNS domain for secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com in the VPC vpc-63170e0b (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: b7d28d81-c2c0-4f44-9642-f22171cf513d)
```

I suspect the error is here because the VPC's private DNS still has an entry from the last time the stack was created.

Is there a way to manually remove entries from the private DNS of the VPC?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is some kind of eventually consistency behavior when the private hosted zone record is deleted. It take some time and during it you will experience this error. Just wait some minutes and try again. It worked for me. Deploys performed after this first success are completed without problems.

Do no try to modify the VPC endpoint record manually because you will not find any "private hosted zone" in Route53. It is some kind of internal private hosted zone for AWS endpoints that is visible only from your VPC when you send a request to your VPC DNS endpoint.

Comment: Comment posted for [Junwei Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8094621/junwei-wu): I agree with the accepted answer and in my experience, I have to wait for 5-8 minutes before they are fully deleted.

Comment: I am receiving the same error, I waited for atleast 30 mins but still getting the same error:
Failed to create resource. private-dns-enabled cannot be set because there is already a conflicting DNS domain for runtime.elastic-inference.us-west-2.amazonaws.com in the VPC vpc-<<VPCID>> (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: <<requesId>> Proxy: null)

Comment: i am facing similar issue and not able to create multiple endpoints with private dns enabled.

Comment: @jayendrabhatt were you able to fix it? I have the same problem and I see it complains of conflicting domain name.

Comment: For those of you who gets the error by applying the CloudFormation changes multiple times in a short period of time, take a coffee break then come back to it. Even though the endpoint might not be created, but as long as it started, it would need some time to clear out.

Answer (score 3):

I received a similar error when trying to rename and VPC endpoint in a CloudFormation stack.
There is no option to wait, so I fixed it by using the following steps:

- Log into the **AWS Console**
- Navigate to `VPC` -> `Vitual Private Cloud` -> `Endpoints`
- In the list of **Endpoints**, find the entry causing the issue
- CLick on the entry and select `Actions` -> `Delete Endpoint`
- Wait for deletion (can take a few minutes)

I then reran my CloudFormation stack and all worked.